# Determining Bases of Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $Y:=span({y_1,y_2})\subset R^4$ and $Z:=span({z_1,z_2,z_3})\subset R^4$ with:

$y_1=(1,1,2,1),y_2=(-1,-1,-1,2)\\
z_1=(1,2,3,-3),z_2=(1,4,4,-2),z_3=(1,3,1,-4)$.

Determine a base for $Y\cap Z$ and for $Y+Z$.

I don't ask for a solution. I rather want to know if I'm on the right track.

So first I have to calculate the span of each set right?
Then (for the first one) i have to look which elements are in both, this would be $Y\cap Z$. And then i have to look for a linear independant set of vectors which is minimal to represent all vectors in $Y\cap Z$.

Right?

Comment: It is important to choose elements that are easy to deal with so for $Y$ you might pick $y_1$ and $y_1+y_2=(0,0,1,3)$. Similarly for $Z$ you might pick $z_1+z_2-2z_3=(0,0,5,3),z_2-z_3=(0,1,3,2),2z_1-z_3=(1,0,2,-4)$. That makes it obvious what vectors are linearly independent and makes it easier to see what is in $Y\cap Z$ etc.

Comment: Hi, can you explain why it is obvious now, which vectors are linbearly independent? I can't see it, without calculating the determinant.

Comment: If $\lambda(0,0,5,3)+\mu(0,1,3,2)+\nu(1,0,2,-4)=0$, then we must have $\nu=0$ to make the first component 0. Then we must have $\mu=0$ to make the second component 0, and then we must have $\lambda=0$ to make the third component 0.

Comment: Hi, with your method i have: $a(0,0,1,3)+b(0,0,5,3)+c(0,1,3,2)+d(1,0,2,-4)=0$ which only is true if a,b,c,d are all equal 0. So $y_1+y_2$, and all your 3 z-combinations are then $Y\cap Z$? I don't know how to form $Y\cap Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $y_1=(1,1,2,1),y_2=(-1,-1,-1,2),z_1=(1,2,3,-3),z_2=(1,4,4,-2),z_3=(1,3,1,-4)$.

Take $y_3=y_1+y_2=(0,0,1,3)$. This is obviously independent of $y_1$, because $\lambda y_3+\mu y_1=0$ implies the first coordinate is 0 and hence $\lambda=0$ and the 3rd coordinate is 0, so $\mu=0$.

Take $z_4=z_1+z_2-2z_4=(0,0,5,3),z_5=z_2-z_3=(0,1,3,2)$ and $z_6=2z_1-z_3=(1,0,2,-4)$. Suppose $\kappa y_3+\lambda z_4+\mu z_5+\nu z_6=0$. Then looking at the 1st coordinate $\nu=0$. Then looking at the 2nd coordinate $\mu=0$. Then looking at the 4th coordinate, we must have $\kappa=-\lambda$. Finally, looking at the 3rd coordinate gives $\kappa=\lambda=0$.

So we have established that $Y+Z=\mathbb{R}^4$. Since $Y$ has dimension 2 and $Z$ has dimension 3, $Y\cap Z$ must have dimension 1. So it remains to find a non-zero vector which belongs to it.

It is clearly not $(0,0,r,s)$, so we look for a linear combination of $z_i$ which is $(1,1,r,s)$. The obvious one is $z_1-z_2+z_3=(1,1,0,-5)$. We now see that $y_1-2(y_1+y_2)=(1,1,0,-5)$. So $(1,1,0,-5)$ is a basis for $Y\cap Z$.

Comment: Is there some Lemma which states, that dim(span(a))=dim(a)? If $Y+Z=R^4$ then one basis for Y+Z must be for sure (1,0,0,0), ...,(0,0,0,1) right?

Comment: Yes, that has to be correct for finite-dimensional vector spaces. $(1,0,0,0)$ is in the space so it must be some linear combination of any basis.

Comment: Just so i understand: And can i establish that Y+Z=R^4 if i just show that: Y+Z has at least 4 independent vectors. (which is what you did there or?)

Comment: That is true. If a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ has dimension 4 then it must be $\mathbb{R}^4$. Think about it. Suppose there was a 5th vector which was linearly independent of the 4 linearly independent basis vectors we already have. Then we would have a set of 5 linearly independent vectors and $\mathbb{R}^4$ would have dimension 5!

Comment: But then there can't be 5 linear independent vectors when the vectors only have 4 coordinates or? So Y+Z in this case has to be $\subseteq$R^4

Comment: Yes. If you are really worried, it is not hard to get $(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,0,1)$ explicitly as linear combinations of $z_4,z_5,z_6,y_3$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41081/discussion-between-saturatedexpo-and-almagest).

Comment: Hi, why is "It is clearly not (0,0,r,s)," clear?

Comment: Because any linear combination of $z_4,z_5,z_6$ with first two coordinates zero must be a multiple of $z_4$ and that has the wrong ratio between the 3rd and 4th coordinates.